# PHP code to show certain text if certain criteria is met

Tags: php

I am making a website in WordPress where I need some help with PHP. The customer is an architect business, who has different categories of building types (example: Apartments, Houses etc.). What I basically want to do is show certain text below the h1 title based on which building type it is. I thought maybe this was possible with some sort of keyword in URL string, however this was just an idea I had.

```
if ($show_title)
{
    $title_content .= apply_filters( 'uncode_before_body_title', '' );
    $title_content .= '<div class="post-title-wrapper"><h1 class="post-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1></div>';
    $title_content .= apply_filters( 'uncode_after_body_title', '' );
}
```

Hope someone is able to help me out! If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello Kristian and welcome. Can you please give us more background of what you tried and what exactly is your question ? Thank you

Comment: Rather than extracting stuff from the URL, this should probably use the existing classification the items already have within the system - so the taxonomy, or a custom category system. (And if no such thing exists yet, you should probably start with setting one up.)